# When is better to call UPDATE STATISTICS? before or after a COMMIT TRANS

Tags: t-sql, transactions

I'm working on an ETL project, actively populating tables with data. Sometimes if something is missing, a whole block of data modifications must be undone, so I'm using a transaction. When something goes wrong, a rollback applies, if not, an UPDATE STATISTICS could help efficiency.

So my question is what would be more efficient, to UPDATE STATISTICS inside the TRANSACTION or after the COMMIT?

Currently working fine as:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE stuffs SET ...
    INSERT things VALUES(...

    UPDATE STATISTICS stuffs
    UPDATE STATISTICS things
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
    RAISERROR( ... -- RAISERROR prevents from executing past this point
END CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
```

But maybe this is better

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE stuffs SET ...
    INSERT things VALUES(...

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
    RAISERROR( ... -- RAISERROR prevents from executing past this point
END CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN

UPDATE STATISTICS stuffs
UPDATE STATISTICS things
```

I've tried both with virtually the same results, but with more data or more rollbacks could be different.

Comment: As your code works, you’re at the wrong platform. what you need is code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the second one.

The transaction will be rolled back when it raises the error(s) if you put them in the try block.

I believe you still need 'update statistics' to improve efficiency even after a rollback applies to your transaction. If so, it is better to keep 'update statistics' after the transaction commits.